# jquery to loop through each row and divide two of the row values into each other

Tags: jquery, function

I have a table that has some inputs populated by jquery.

I want to divide the jquery value by the user inputted qty.

I am trying to do this with a function called qtypercheckas below:

```
function qtypercheck(){
     //for each table row 
        // var lineqty= input[name^="product"] divide input[name^="checkedsizes"]
        //set value of input[name^="qtypercheck"]=lineqty    
}
```

the complete fiddle can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/emL6x/36/

if I try loop through the table with `$('.authors-list tr').each(function(){` the loop is not one per row so unsure.

to summarize, need to populate the `cubespercheck` field with the result of `qty` / `checkedsizes`

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd ditch the qtypercheck() function and just add a line to your countchecks() function:

```
function countChecks() {
    $('.authors-list tr').each(function () {
        var count = 0;

        var hdn = $(this).find('input[name^="checkedsizes"]');
        count = $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length;
        hdn.val(count);
        if(count>0) $(this).find('input[name^="qtypercheck"]').val($('input', this).eq(1).val() / count);
    });
   // qtypercheck();
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/emL6x/37/)**

Comment: Awesome. thanks a million. How would I round that to a single decimal place? thanks again.

Comment: Change the line to `if (count > 0) $(this).find('input[name^="qtypercheck"]').val(Math.round($('input', this).eq(1).val() / count * 10) / 10);`

Comment: Thanks a million. this does not work. the entire line just miss functions without any output errors. Thanks again.

Comment: Wait, is it thanks a million or it's not working for you? It works fine in a fiddle.